# How to sign in kubernetes dashboard?

Tags: kubernetes, dashboard

I just upgraded kubeadm and kubelet to v1.8.0. And install the dashboard following the official [document](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard).

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

After that, I started the dashboard by running

```
$ kubectl proxy --address="192.168.0.101" -p 8001 --accept-hosts='^*$'
```

Then fortunately, I was able to access the dashboard thru http://192.168.0.101:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/

I was redirected to a login page like this which I had never met before. 
[image] It looks like that there are two ways of authentication.

I tried to upload the `/etc/kubernetes/admin.conf` as the kubeconfig but got failed. Then I tried to use the token I got from `kubeadm token list` to sign in but failed again.

The question is how I can sign in the dashboard. It looks like they added a lot of security mechanism than before. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see a programming question here. Try serverfault.com instead.

Comment: If you're NOT on localhost, you may be required to use https only, otherwise login form will failed silently (without err msg). Details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53957413/how-to-access-kubernetes-dashboard-from-outside-network

Comment: @Jolta Devops is now a programming activity thanks to kubernetes, you'll to face it ;)

Answer (score 247, accepted):

> As of release 1.7 Dashboard supports user authentication based on:
>
> - [`Authorization: Bearer <token>`](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/v2.0.0/docs/user/access-control/README.md#authorization-header) header passed in every request to Dashboard. Supported from release 1.6. Has the highest priority. If present, login view will not be shown.
> - [Bearer Token](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/v2.0.0/docs/user/access-control/README.md#bearer-token) that can be used on Dashboard [login view](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/v2.0.0/docs/user/access-control/README.md#login-view).
> - [Username/password](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/v2.0.0/docs/user/access-control/README.md#basic) that can be used on Dashboard [login view](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/v2.0.0/docs/user/access-control/README.md#login-view).
> - [Kubeconfig](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/v2.0.0/docs/user/access-control/README.md#kubeconfig) file that can be used on Dashboard [login view](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/v2.0.0/docs/user/access-control/README.md#login-view).

— [Dashboard on Github](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard)

### Token

Here `Token` can be `Static Token`, `Service Account Token`, `OpenID Connect Token` from [Kubernetes Authenticating](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/), but not the kubeadm `Bootstrap Token`.

With kubectl, we can get an service account (eg. deployment controller) created in kubernetes by default.

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get secret
# All secrets with type 'kubernetes.io/service-account-token' will allow to log in.
# Note that they have different privileges.
NAME                                     TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
deployment-controller-token-frsqj        kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         22h

$ kubectl -n kube-system describe secret deployment-controller-token-frsqj
Name:         deployment-controller-token-frsqj
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name=deployment-controller
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid=64735958-ae9f-11e7-90d5-02420ac00002

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1025 bytes
namespace:  11 bytes
token:      eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.OqFc4CE1Kh6T3BTCR4XxDZR8gaF1MvH4M3ZHZeCGfO-sw-D0gp826vGPHr_0M66SkGaOmlsVHmP7zmTi-SJ3NCdVO5viHaVUwPJ62hx88_JPmSfD0KJJh6G5QokKfiO0WlGN7L1GgiZj18zgXVYaJShlBSz5qGRuGf0s1jy9KOBt9slAN5xQ9_b88amym2GIXoFyBsqymt5H-iMQaGP35tbRpewKKtly9LzIdrO23bDiZ1voc5QZeAZIWrizzjPY5HPM1qOqacaY9DcGc7akh98eBJG_4vZqH2gKy76fMf0yInFTeNKr45_6fWt8gRM77DQmPwb3hbrjWXe1VvXX_g
```

### Kubeconfig

The dashboard needs the user in the kubeconfig file to have either `username & password` or `token`, but `admin.conf` only has `client-certificate`.  You can edit the config file to add the token that was extracted using the method above.

```
$ kubectl config set-credentials cluster-admin --token=bearer_token
```

## Alternative (Not recommended for Production)

Here are two ways to bypass the authentication, but use for caution.

### Deploy dashboard with HTTP

```
$ kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/alternative/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Dashboard can be loaded at http://localhost:8001/ui with `kubectl proxy`.

### Granting admin privileges to Dashboard's Service Account

```
$ cat <<EOF | kubectl create -f -
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
EOF
```

Afterwards you can use <kbd>Skip</kbd> option on login page to access Dashboard.

If you are using dashboard version v1.10.1 or later, you must also add `--enable-skip-login` to the deployment's command line arguments. You can do so by adding it to the `args` in `kubectl edit deployment/kubernetes-dashboard --namespace=kube-system`.

Example:

```
      containers:
      - args:
        - --auto-generate-certificates
        - --enable-skip-login            # <-- add this line
        image: k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.1
```

Comment: Can you give us an example how to create a user then login with token ? I still don't know how to use token act like an user.

Comment: See [Static Token File](https://kubernetes.io/docs/admin/authentication/#static-token-file) in Kubernetes Authenticating

Comment: I'm using this for my home server

Comment: This allows me to skip, but doesn't give me authorization to see anything. `is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kubernetes-dashboard:kubernetes-dashboard"`

Comment: The URL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/alternative/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
returns a 404 code. Is there a new one?

Comment: @B.Stucke https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/alternative.yaml

Answer (score 148):

## TL;DR

To get the token in a single oneliner:

```
kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | awk '/^deployment-controller-token-/{print $1}') | awk '$1=="token:"{print $2}'
```

This assumes that your ~/.kube/config is present and valid. And also that `kubectl config get-contexts` indicates that you are using the correct context (cluster and namespace) for the dashboard you are logging into.

## Explanation

I derived this answer from what I learned from @silverfox's answer. That is a very informative write up. Unfortunately it falls short of telling you how to actually put the information into practice. Maybe I've been doing DevOps too long, but I think in shell. It's much more difficult for me to learn or teach in English.

Here is that oneliner with line breaks and indents for readability:

```
kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(
  kubectl -n kube-system get secret | \
  awk '/^deployment-controller-token-/{print $1}'
) | \
awk '$1=="token:"{print $2}'
```

There are 4 distinct commands and they get called in this order:

- Line 2 - This is the first command from @silverfox's **Token** section.
- Line 3 - Print only the first *field* of the line beginning with `deployment-controller-token-` (which is the pod name)
- Line 1 - This is the second command from @silverfox's **Token** section.
- Line 5 - Print only the second *field* of the line whose first *field* is "token:"

Comment: Is there a powershell equivalent to awk?

Comment: @duct_tape_coder just kubectl -n kube-system get secrets and find the tokenm with name deployment-controller-token-SOMEHASH, afterwards just kubectl -n kube-system describe secret deployment-controller-token-SOMEHASH. That's what the awk does.

Comment: Great answer. To take it one more step:

```kubectl describe secret $(kubectl get secret | awk '/^dashboard-token-/{print $1}') | awk '$1=="token:"{print $2}'```

Or push right to your clipboard

```kubectl describe secret $(kubectl get secret | awk '/^dashboard-token-/{print $1}') | awk '$1=="token:"{print $2}' | xclip -selection clipboard -i```

Comment: @duct_tape_coder `kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard describe secret $(kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret | sls admin-user | ForEach-Object { $_ -Split '\s+' } | Select -First 1)` from https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md

Comment: TLDR: `The connection to the server localhost:8080 was refused - did you specify the right host or port?`

Comment: Single call to kubectl and leveraging jq and base64: kubectl -n kube-system get secret -o json | jq -r '.items[] | select(.metadata.name | startswith("deployment-controller-token")) | .data.token' | base64 --decode

Answer (score 58):

If you don't want to grant admin permission to dashboard service account, you can create cluster admin service account.

```
$ kubectl create serviceaccount cluster-admin-dashboard-sa
$ kubectl create clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-dashboard-sa \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
  --serviceaccount=default:cluster-admin-dashboard-sa
```

And then, you can use the token of just created cluster admin service account.

```
$ kubectl get secret | grep cluster-admin-dashboard-sa
cluster-admin-dashboard-sa-token-6xm8l   kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         18m
$ kubectl describe secret cluster-admin-dashboard-sa-token-6xm8l
```

I quoted it from giantswarm guide - https://docs.giantswarm.io/guides/install-kubernetes-dashboard/

Comment: This one worked just fine for me while the accepted answer was sign in me but with some authorisation errors.

Comment: Note that this command gives the service account a lot of rights and might not be advisable in a production environment.

Comment: might wanna add the serviceaccount under kube-system also since this is where dashboard lives

Comment: Worked for me! i was exposing the service with port 8001 and used a SSH tunnel to access from my local machine.

Comment: This does not work, on kubectl 1.24.1
I'm trying "kubectl get secret -A" and I can't see anything with "cluster-admin-dashboard-sa"

Comment: It changed on 1.24, it is no longer automatically generated.
I've tested this guide https://itnext.io/big-change-in-k8s-1-24-about-serviceaccounts-and-their-secrets-4b909a4af4e0 with yaml file and it worked

Comment: does not work on latest version 1.25.4

Answer (score 29):

Combining two answers: [49992698](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49992698/747579) and [47761914](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47761914/747579) :

```
# Create service account
kubectl create serviceaccount -n kube-system cluster-admin-dashboard-sa

# Bind ClusterAdmin role to the service account
kubectl create clusterrolebinding -n kube-system cluster-admin-dashboard-sa \
  --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
  --serviceaccount=kube-system:cluster-admin-dashboard-sa

# Parse the token
TOKEN=$(kubectl describe secret -n kube-system $(kubectl get secret -n kube-system | awk '/^cluster-admin-dashboard-sa-token-/{print $1}') | awk '$1=="token:"{print $2}')
```

Comment: It can happen that secret is located in namespace other than kube-system, so one might want to omit "-n kube-system" from the above.

Comment: I get a bunch of error messages in the Dashboard, e.g. `namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:test:cluster-admin-dashboard-sa" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope` for all the different resources

Comment: @isapir the namespace needs to be the same across the board. The edited answer now adds the `kube-system` namespace on all commands, which works.

Comment: @T0xicCode Still doesn't work.  I see no data and get messages like the following: `namespaces is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:kube-system:cluster-admin-dashboard-sa" cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope: RBAC: clusterrole.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "cluster-admin" not found`

Comment: @isapir did you delete the service account and re-create it?

Comment: @T0xicCode I believe that the old account that I had was with a different name, or perhaps I deleted it in the past, as that didn't generate an error.  I did have to delete the `clusterrolebinding cluster-admin-dashboard-sa` as that triggered an error that it already existed.

Answer (score 26):

You need to follow these steps before the token authentication

1. Create a Cluster Admin service account

   ```
   kubectl create serviceaccount dashboard -n default
   ```
2. Add the cluster binding rules to your dashboard account

   ```
   kubectl create clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin -n default --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:dashboard
   ```
3. Get the secret token with this command

   ```
   kubectl get secret $(kubectl get serviceaccount dashboard -o jsonpath="{.secrets[0].name}") -o jsonpath="{.data.token}" | base64 --decode
   ```
4. Choose token authentication in the  Kubernetes dashboard login page
   [image]
5. Now you can able to login

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me. Thanks! Though the token hat a % sign at the end which I had to remove.

Comment: I get no output from command 3.

Answer (score 19):

this is finally what works now (2023)

create two files `create-service-cccount.yaml`

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

and `create-cluster-role-binding.yaml`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

then run

```
kubectl apply -f create-service-cccount.yaml
kubectl apply -f create-cluster-role-binding.yaml
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard create token admin-user
```

for latest update please check
https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md

Comment: This worked for me...in 2023

Comment: This is the one guys, you need the create token step or you won't find anything with all those get secret commands.

Answer (score 14):

A self-explanatory simple one-liner to extract token for kubernetes dashboard login.

```
kubectl describe secret -n kube-system | grep deployment -A 12
```

Copy the token and paste it on the kubernetes dashboard under token sign in option and you are good to use kubernetes dashboard

Answer (score 13):

However, if you are using **After kubernetes 1.24** version,

> creating service accounts will not generate tokens
> , instead should use following command.

```
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard create token admin-user
```

Comment: since many new to kubernetes will read this, maybe add that before creating the token there still needs to be a, for example serviceaccount, with the rights to access everything. In your case:
`kubectl create serviceaccount admin-user -n kubernetes-dashboard` and
`kubectl create clusterrolebinding admin-user-binding -n kubernetes-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kubernetes-dashboard:admin-user`
right?

Answer (score 9):

All the previous answers are good to me. But a straight forward answer on my side would come from https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md. Just use `kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')`. You will have many values for some keys (`Name`, `Namespace`, `Labels`, ..., `token`). The most important is the `token` that corresponds to your name. copy that token and paste it in the token box. Hope this helps.

Comment: After trying several of the answers above, this one answer worked. I copied a token out, pasted it, and presto, Im in.

Comment: Link is dead. Here's a new one: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md

Answer (score 8):

For version **1.26.0/1.26.1** at **2023**,

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.7.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml
kubectl create serviceaccount admin-user -n kubernetes-dashboard
kubectl create clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin -n kubernetes-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kubernetes-dashboard:admin-user
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard create token admin-user
```

The newest guide: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me in May 2023 with Kubernetes v1.27

Comment: 3rd command returned error, here is corrected one `kubectl create clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin -n kubernetes-dashboard --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=kubernetes-dashboard:admin-user`

Comment: Working as of nov/2023 +1

Answer (score 7):

You can get the token:

```
kubectl describe secret -n kube-system | grep deployment -A 12
```

Take the Token value which is something like

```
token:    eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsI...
```

Use port-forward to /kubernetes-dashboard:

```
kubectl port-forward -n kubernetes-dashboard service/kubernetes-dashboard 8080:443 --address='0.0.0.0'
```

Access the Site Using:

```
https://<IP-of-Master-node>:8080/
```

Provide the Token when asked.
Note the `https` on the URL. Tested site on Firefox because With new Updates Google Chrome has become strict of not allowing traffic from unknown SSL certificates.

Also note, the 8080 port should be opened in the VM of Master Node.

Answer (score 1):

The skip login has been disabled by default due to security issues. https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/issues/2672

in your dashboard yaml add this arg

```
- --enable-skip-login
```

to get it back

Answer (score 0):

Download 
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/src/deploy/alternative/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml

add

```
type: NodePort for the Service
```

And then run this command:

```
kubectl apply -f kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

Find the exposed port with the command :

```
kubectl get services -n kube-system
```

You should be able to get the dashboard at http://hostname:exposedport/
with no authentication

Comment: This is absolutely terrible advice. Even if it's technically correct

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to obtain the kubernetes-dashboard token:

```
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret -o=jsonpath='{.items[?(@.metadata.annotations.kubernetes\.io/service-account\.name=="kubernetes-dashboard")].data.token}' | base64 --decode
```

**Explanation:**

1. Get all the `secret` in the `kubernetes-dashboard` name space.
2. Look at the `items` array, and match for: `metadata` -> `annotations` -> `kubernetes.io/service-account.name` == `kubernetes-dashboard`
3. Print `data` -> `token`
4. Decode content. (If you perform `kubectl describe secret`, the `token` is already decoded.)