# Kubernetes Dashboard access using config file Not enough data to create auth info structure.

Tags: kubernetes

I am trying to access the kubernetes Dashboard using the config file. From the authentication when I select config file its giving ‘`Not enough data to create auth info structure`.’  Bu the same config file work for kubectl command.

[image]

here is my config file.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://kubemaster:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
```

Any help to resolve this issue?

Thanks
SR

Comment: For anyone wondering about this on Docker Desktop for Windows 10, using Minikube is a lot easier - https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/hello-minikube/ (also https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/start/)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

After looking at this answer [How to sign in kubernetes dashboard?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664104/how-to-sign-in-kubernetes-dashboard) and source code figured the kubeconfig authentication.

After kubeadm install on the master server get the **default** service account token and add it to config file. Then use the config file to authenticate.

You can use this to add the token.

```
#!/bin/bash
TOKEN=$(kubectl -n kube-system describe secret default| awk '$1=="token:"{print $2}')

kubectl config set-credentials kubernetes-admin --token="${TOKEN}"
```

your config file should be looking like this.

```
kubectl config view |cut -c1-50|tail -10
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
    token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.ey
```

Comment: can anyone help with the equivalent of this awk `'$1=="token:"{print $2}'` in PowerShell? thanks

Comment: @sebagomez maybe you can just run `kubectl -n kube-system describe secret default` and copy the token manually.

Comment: Make sure you select the kubernetes cluster from your config.  In the case of docker for desktop on Mac, mine was named "docker-desktop" thus in the kubectl command in the answer change "kubernetes-admin" to "docker-desktop".

Comment: @sebagomez just use
`$TOKEN=((kubectl -n kube-system describe secret default | Select-String "token:") -split " +")[1]`
and `kubectl config set-credentials docker-for-desktop --token="${TOKEN}"`

Comment: Well I'm 2 years late, but for sebagomez this is one way you can recreate the awk functionality in Powershell: `((kubectl -n kube-system describe secret default) | Select-String "token:").ToString().Split(":")[1].Trim()`

Comment: This does not seem to work anymore: `Error from server (NotFound): secrets "default" not found`

Answer (score 17):

Only authentication options specified by `--authentication-mode` flag is supported in kubeconfig file.

You can auth with token (any token in `kube-system` namespace):

```
$ kubectl get secrets -n kube-system
$ kubectl get secret $SECRET_NAME -n=kube-system -o json | jq -r '.data["token"]' | base64 -d > user_token.txt
```

and auth with the token (see **user_token.txt** file).

Comment: Thanks Denis. user token works now. still trying to figure out kubeconfig based authenticaiton.

Comment: FYI, for those who had problems with this step, make sure to `brew install jq`. It's a JSON command line parser.

Answer (score 16):

Two things are going on here

- the Kubernetes Dashboard Application needs an authentication token
- *and* this authentication token must be linked to an account with sufficient privileges.

The usual way to deploy the Dashboard Application is just

- to `kubectl apply` a YAML file pulled from the configuration *recommended* at the [Github project(for the dashboard)](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard): `/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml` ⟹ [master](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/raw/master/aio/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml)•[v1.10.1](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/raw/v1.10.1/src/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml)
- then to run `kubectl proxy` and access the dashbord through the [locally mapped Port 8001](http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/).

However this default configuration is generic and minimal. It just maps a role binding with minimal privileges. And, especially on DigitalOcean, the `kubeconfig` file provided when provisioning the cluster lacks the actual token, which is necessary to log into the dashboard.

Thus, to fix these shortcomings, we need to ensure there is an account, which has a RoleBinding to the **cluster-admin** ClusterRole in the Namespace **kube-system**. The above mentioned default setup just provides a binding to `kubernetes-dashboard-minimal`.
We can fix that by deplyoing explicitly

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
```

And then we also need to get the token for this ServiceAccount...

- `kubectl get serviceaccount -n kube-system` will list you all service accounts. Check that the one you want/created is present
- `kubectl get secrets -n kube-system` should list a secret *for this account*
- and with `kubectl describe secret -n kube-system admin-user-token-`**XXXXXX** you'd get the information about the token.

The other answers to this question provide ample hints, how this access could be scripted in a convenient way (like e.g. using awk, using grep, using `kubectl get` with `-o=json` and piping to jq, or using `-o=jsonpath`)

You can then either:

- store this token into a text file and upload this
- edit your `kubeconfig` file and paste in the token to the *admin user provided there*

Comment: This is so insanely complicated that I've just kept using kubectl instead

Comment: mostly agreed... kubectl is a must.

However, the dashboard really comes in handy when you have an elaborate cluster and temporarily want to tweak some resource requirements or adjust some horizontal scale on the fly

Comment: As of Feb 2023, 3 secrets are listed related to Kubernetes Dashboard, with postfixes `-certs`, `-csrf`, and `-key-holder`. Not clear which one to use.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I had a similar issue, it appears as of recently you need to manually create this token. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72256006/service-account-secret-is-not-listed-how-to-fix-it

Answer (score 8):

If you want to get past dashboard's authentification prompt *and* then be able to do admin-things on the dashboard, I recommmend this: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Creating-sample-user.

Comment: this is the only answer which hints at the really essential point here: you need a role binding to the **cluster-admin** role _in namespace **kube-system**_

Comment: I found instructions here: https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md

Answer (score 6):

1 - Assuming one has followed the directions to setup the dashboard here.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eks/latest/userguide/dashboard-tutorial.html

2 - And your normal kubectl access works from the command line (i.e. kubectl get services).

3 - And you are able to login manually to the Dashboard with the token (with kubectl -n kube-system describe secret ...), by using copy/paste.

4 - But now you want to use the "Kubeconfig" (instead of "Token") option to login to the Dashboard, for simplicity.

[image]

Solution:

- Find your user in the config file, that is used to access the cluster.
- The user is "kubernetes-admin" in this original posted question.
- Add a line with the "token:".
- Dont forget this is YAML, so use spaces, not tabs.

Here is what it should look like...

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: REDACTED
    server: https://kubemaster:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: REDACTED
    client-key-data: REDACTED
    token: PUT_YOUR_TOKEN_HERE_THAT_YOU_USED_TO_MANUALLY_LOGIN
```

Answer (score 2):

Answers can be dependent on versions. FYI, I am using K8s v1.20 and Dashboard v2.1.0 First I created a dashboard admin service account via the following dashboardsvcacct.yaml file

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: dashboard-admin
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

and applied it to the cluster via

```
#kubectl apply -f dashboardsvcacct.yaml
#serviceaccount/dashboard-admin created
```

Then I created a role binding to allow the above service account cluster-admin role access instead of sharing the kubernetes-admin account. Done via the following dashboardrolebinding.yaml

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: dashboard-admin
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: dashboard-admin
  namespace: kubernetes-dashboard
```

and applied it to the cluster via

```
#kubectl apply -f dashboardrolebinding.yaml
#clusterrolebinding.rbac.authorization.k8s.io/dashboard-admin created
```

Then extracted the token from the newly created dashboard-admin account associated with the kubernetes-dashboard namespace via

```
#kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard describe secret $(kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard get secret | grep dashboard-admin | awk '{print $1}')
```

the output includes the token below. I have shortened the token for posting purposes. Note not to include linebreaks when copying/pasting from terminal.

```
Name:         dashboard-admin-token-9pzgf
Namespace:    kubernetes-dashboard
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name: dashboard-admin
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid: 7efde521-60fd-40f3-9fe0-2097c123421c

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
token:      eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Im1OVl<Shortened for posting>
ca.crt:     1066 bytes
namespace:  20 bytes
```

Copying and pasting the full token from the above output allowed me to access the dashboard via the Token option, but this is a pain to do every time.

The main question was being able to use a Config File option. The config file does not need to contain any X509 certificates as those are not/cannot be used by the dashboard. Also, it is not secure to share out the kubernetes-admin config file entirely which includes the both the certificate and private key. So the config file needed to access the dashboard can be based on the kubernetes-admin config without the kubernetes-admin data, since only the cluster server API target and public ca cert data are needed. The rest of the file is is information from the dashboard-admin service account including the token. The config file needs to look like the below. Note that everything under the "cluster" section will be specific to your install. The "contexts" and "users" section that will be the same, except the token for your install.

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRVJUSUZJQ0FURS0tL<Shortened for posting>
    server: https://10.175.0.3:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: dashboard-admin
  name: dashboard-admin@kubernetes
current-context: dashboard-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: dashboard-admin
  user:
    token: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Im1OVl<Same Token as above, Shortened for posting>
```

Pointing the dashboard UI to that config file allowed me to login.

Answer (score 1):

For me i realised i was following a slightly out of date tutorial for installing the dashboard (i was installing v1 of the dashboard, but v2 exists).

- First go to the [official source](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/README.md) which will instruct you the correct most up to date version to install.
- Then [Create An Authentication Token (RBAC)](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/access-control/creating-sample-user.md)

Now you can use the token to login to the dashboard.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I was using `kubectl proxy` to access the dashboard. I fixed it by accessing the `minikube dashboard` on the physical machine that was running minikube.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see dashboard in action before going through a major investment setting up security, here is the way I got things going quickly. I did this with `v2.0.0-rc7`:

- Install with [the alternative method](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/9da51fcdb2d0f488648e02f8a621987651bd544c/docs/user/installation.md#alternative-setup), which just sets things up a little less securely to start with.
- The `ClusterRoleRef` that installs with this method needs to be replaced with [this one](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/9da51fcdb2d0f488648e02f8a621987651bd544c/docs/user/access-control/README.md#official-release). (You need to delete the existing one first with `kubectl delete ...`, then add it.)
- The [second paragraph here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/tree/9da51fcdb2d0f488648e02f8a621987651bd544c/docs/user/access-control#login-view) documents the "skip method". Update your `deployment` to get that set up.

Now you can go to the web page and click "skip". Voila! All your keys are exposed with no password. Pray nobody gets ahold of that link!

But wait, you say it's still too hard to get in? If you have a load balancer installed, here's two additional steps:

- `kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard edit service kubernetes-dashboard` will allow you to change the service spec to `type: LoadBalancer`.
- If your load balancer is set up properly, `kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard describe service kubernetes-dashboard` will now show you the IP address that it has kindly put your insecure dashboard on.

Now you have an insecure port with no password to easily browse your crown jewels. Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

There are two method to provide kubernetes resources access.

1. User
2. Service account
3. User. create user using crt and key. Assign role and bindings.  However you cannot access dashboard using user as it is based on cert/key
4. service account.
5. create namespace, service account, role and rolebindings.  Assign rolebindings to role then assign to service account using kubectl rolebinding command.

then get the secret from kubectl get secret. The secret name will start with service account name.  Whenever you create a service account, secret also created for it.

copy the only token to dashboard webgui to gain access.

If you provided admin and admin rolebinding then you will get full access, else, the access enabled in role will be available in dashboard.