# Jenkins updating PODs on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

During a search on updating PODs in a Kubernetes cluster I found a Jenkis plugin called kubernetes-cd, however, I am in doubt about how to establish a secure connection with the plugin and Kubernetes and would like to know how to set up a user and password or register an ssh key in the cluster that allows this external connection?

I found in the Kubernetes documentation on Secrets([link](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/)), but I'm not sure if it serves only for internal cluster authentication or if it serves to set up accounts for plugin connections or other external media.

Answer (score 1):

[Kubernetes-cd](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/kubernetes-cd/) 3 options are supported:

1. **Authenticate with Kube config file** - Get the kubeconfig file from
   the workspace path.
2. **Fetch cluster details through SSH connection to the master node** -
   Get the `~/.kube/config` file through an SSH connection to the master
   node.
3. **Fill credentials details directly** - Fill the contents in kubeconfig
   file directly.

You need configure ~/.kube/config on you runner.

Example:

```
echo "$KUBE_CA_CERT" > /ca.pem
kubectl config set-cluster cluster --server=${KUBE_MASTER_URL} --certificate-authority=/ca.pem
kubectl config set-credentials user --token=${KUBE_TOKEN}
kubectl config set-context context --cluster=cluster --user=user
kubectl config use-context context
```

- `$KUBE_CA_CERT` - usually lies on the master
  `/etc/kubernetes/ssl/ca.pem`
- `$KUBE_MASTER_URL` - you kubernetes
  master url with port
- `$KUBE_TOKEN` - you token, how get it -
  [Kubernetes Dashboard access using config file Not enough data to create auth info structure.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228534/kubernetes-dashboard-access-using-config-file-not-enough-data-to-create-auth-inf/48241411#48241411)