# Unable to sign in with default config file generated with Oracle cloud

Tags: kubernetes, yaml, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I have generated a config file with Oracle cloud for Kubernetes, The generated file keeps throwing the error "Not enough data to create auth info structure.
", wat are methods for fixing this

I have created a new oracle cloud account and set up a cluster for Kubernetes (small with only 2 nodes using quick setup) when I upload the generated config file, to Kubernetes dashboard, it throws the error "Not enough data to create auth info structure".

[image: problem screen]

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: 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
    server: https://czgkn3bmu4t.uk-london-1.clusters.oci.oraclecloud.com:6443
  name: cluster-czgkn3bmu4t
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: cluster-czgkn3bmu4t
    user: user-czgkn3bmu4t
  name: context-czgkn3bmu4t
current-context: context-czgkn3bmu4t
kind: ''
users:
- name: user-czgkn3bmu4t
  user:
    exec:
      apiVersion: client.authentication.k8s.io/v1beta1
      args:
      - ce
      - cluster
      - generate-token
      - --cluster-id
      - ocid1.cluster.oc1.uk-london-1.aaaaaaaaae3deztchfrwinjwgiztcnbqheydkyzyhbrgkmbvmczgkn3bmu4t
      command: oci
      env: []
```

if you could help me resolve this I would be extremely grateful

Comment: Maybe this one will help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48228534/kubernetes-dashboard-access-using-config-file-not-enough-data-to-create-auth-inf Seems like similar issue.

Comment: did you manage to resolve the issue ?

Comment: I didn't find a solution to this issue that worked, I did find a workaround though using minikube and learning the command line methods

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to solve this by downloading a v1 `kubeconfig`. Then specifying the `--token-version=1.0.0` flag on the create `kubeconfig` command.

```
oci ce cluster create-kubeconfig <options> --token-version=1.0.0
```

Then use that `kubeconfig` in the dashboard.