# How to access Kubernetes Dashboard from outside network

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-dashboard

I am trying to access the kubernetes Dashboard using the Token method outside the network.

I ran these 2 commands to get the token

```
kubectl -n kube-system get secret

kubectl -n kube-system describe secret replicaset-controller-token-2p4fk
```

Copy paste output token into K8 Login page.

I'm getting this error browser console when I click on Sign in button (Page is not loading).

[image]

I'm running k8 on the internal server using the command:

```
kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'
```

And trying to access the k8 UI console from **outside network**.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
vendor.bd425c26.js:6 Error during global settings reload:  Object
:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/api/v1/rbac/status:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)
vendor.bd425c26.js:6 Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"MSG_LOGIN_UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR\n","status":401,"config":{"method":"GET","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"api/v1/rbac/status","headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*"}},"statusText":"Unauthorized","xhrStatus":"complete","resource":{}}
```

I even tried these steps but no luck the page is not loading on clicking Sign in button.

```
$ kubectl -n kube-system get secret
# All secrets with type 'kubernetes.io/service-account-token' will allow to log in.
# Note that they have different privileges.
NAME                                     TYPE                                  DATA      AGE
deployment-controller-token-frsqj        kubernetes.io/service-account-token   3         22h

$ kubectl -n kube-system describe secret deployment-controller-token-frsqj
Name:         deployment-controller-token-frsqj
Namespace:    kube-system
Labels:       <none>
Annotations:  kubernetes.io/service-account.name=deployment-controller
              kubernetes.io/service-account.uid=64735958-ae9f-11e7-90d5-02420ac00002

Type:  kubernetes.io/service-account-token

Data
====
ca.crt:     1025 bytes
namespace:  11 bytes
token:      eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJrdWJlcm5ldGVzL3NlcnZpY2VhY2NvdW50Iiwia3ViZXJuZXRlcy5pby9zZXJ2aWNlYWNjb3VudC9uYW1lc3BhY2UiOiJrdWJlLXN5c3RlbSIsImt1YmVybmV0ZXMuaW8vc2VydmljZWFjY291bnQvc2VjcmV0Lm5hbWUiOiJkZXBsb3ltZW50LWN
```

**Here is my Kube/config file**

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    certificate-authority-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBDRV..
    server: https://192.168.15.97:6443
  name: kubernetes
contexts:
- context:
    cluster: kubernetes
    user: kubernetes-admin
  name: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
current-context: kubernetes-admin@kubernetes
kind: Config
preferences: {}
users:
- name: kubernetes-admin
  user:
    client-certificate-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBD..
    client-key-data: LS0tLS1CRUdJTiBSU0EgUFJ..
```

And why is that I'm not seeing **Skip**  auth button next to Sign button?

**I tried these steps as well:**

Run the following commands:

1. This command will create a service account for the dashboard in the default namespace

   `$kubectl create serviceaccount dashboard -n default`
2. This command will add the cluster binding rules to your dashboard account

   kubectl create clusterrolebinding dashboard-admin -n default \
     --clusterrole=cluster-admin \
     --serviceaccount=default:dashboard
3. This command will give you the token required for your dashboard login

   `$kubectl get secret $(kubectl get serviceaccount dashboard -o jsonpath="{.secrets[0].name}") -o jsonpath="{.data.token}" | base64 --decode`
   Can some help me here what am i missing out.

**Some Findings:** [Link](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above)
kubectl proxy command only allows HTTP connection. For domains other than localhost and 127.0.0.1 it will not be possible to sign in. Nothing will happen after clicking Sign in button on login page.

```
kubectl proxy
```

Doesn't support https calls.

**Is there a way to run *kubectl proxy* command along with Kubernetes Server IP Address from an outside/Local windows network ?**

**Note:**
The local system is a Windows 10 & K8 is a Linux server.
Docker Version: 18.09 & k8 Version: v1.13.1

Thanks,

Answer (score 8):

I have this issue when I try to get access to the dashboard via `kubectl proxy` using plain http and public ip.

Error details: `kubectl proxy` produces errors `http: proxy error: context canceled` in console, in browser after you click "sign in" one of the requests which ends with `/plugin/config` returns json with `MSG_LOGIN_UNAUTHORIZED_ERROR` but the browser doesn't display any error.

The solution ([source](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/blob/master/docs/user/accessing-dashboard/README.md))

```
kubectl port-forward -n kubernetes-dashboard service/kubernetes-dashboard 8443:443 --address 0.0.0.0
```

Of course you can use your interface ip instead of 0.0.0.0 if you want to bind it to one interface only. Then go to `https://your.external.ip:8443/`, it'll redirect you to `https://your.external.ip:8443/#/login` and you'll be asked for the token. Next, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47761914/1013183):

```
kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret \
| awk '/^deployment-controller-token-/{print $1}') | awk '$1=="token:"{print $2}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it worked for me. What are the security implications of this approach? How can I make the service available all the time without running from the command line.? Thanks

Comment: @yaach Sorry, it was too long time ago and I try to avoid working with k8s since then. So I just don't remember.

Answer (score 3):

https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Accessing-Dashboard---1.7.X-and-above

I have a note:

The Dashboard should not be exposed publicly using kubectl proxy command as it only allows HTTP connection. For domains other than localhost and 127.0.0.1 it will not be possible to sign in. Nothing will happen after clicking Sign in button on login page.

Answer (score 2):

In case you have ssh access to the Kubernetes, you can execute on the machine running the cluster:

```
kubectl proxy --address 0.0.0.0 --accept-hosts '.*'
```

And then create a local port forwarding:

```
ssh -L:8001:XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:8001 username@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
```

where `username` is your username using to connect to the machine and `XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX` is the IP address of the master node. Then you would be able to pass the token and access the dashboard.

Of course, this is a very dirty trick and I would hardly advise against using it in a production environment.

Answer (score 1):

with this you able to see the dashboard from the net

```
microk8s kubectl port-forward -n kube-system service/kubernetes-dashboard 443:443 --address 0.0.0.0
```

You can then access the Dashboard at `https://<server-host/ip>`

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you are using wrong secret for `Bearer Token`. Generally, you have to create `ServiceAccount` and then assign it appropriate service role via `ClusterRoleBinding` entitle log in to Dashboard using `Bearer Token`. Find more information about Kubernetes Dashboard `Bearer Token` authorization [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/dashboard/wiki/Creating-sample-user).

Comment: I have update my question please check now, i have tried these steps as well.

Comment: What namespace do you use for `kubernetes-dashboard`?

Comment: kube-system namespace

Answer (score 0):

for enter in dashboard in a vcluster with virtual machines need a handler netwroks for external ip containers i have a post from this https://piensoluegoinstalo.com/kubernetes-cluster-dashboard-on-premise/

the answers is use metallb

```
https://piensoluegoinstalo.com/kubernetes-cluster-dashboard-on-premise/
```

```
vi metallb.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 192.168.1.240-192.168.1.250
```

```
kubectl create -f metallb.yaml
```

Create certificate for you ip external of a container dashboard and add this resolver in hosts file resolve ip, i used "dashboard" for name domain

```
mkdir $HOME/certs
cd $HOME/certs
openssl genrsa -out dashboard.key 2048
openssl rsa -in dashboard.key -out dashboard.key
openssl req -sha256 -new -key dashboard.key -out dashboard.csr -subj '/CN=dashboard'
openssl x509 -req -sha256 -days 365 -in dashboard.csr -signkey dashboard.key -out dashboard.crt
```

```
kubectl -n kube-system create secret generic kubernetes-dashboard-certs --from-file=$HOME/certs
```

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/master/aio/deploy/recommended/kubernetes-dashboard.yaml
```

```
kubectl -n kube-system edit service kubernetes-dashboard
```

CHANGE TYPE TO LOAD BALANCER

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: |
      {"apiVersion":"v1","kind":"Service","metadata":{"annotations":{},"labels":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"},"name":"kubernetes-dashboard","namespace":"kube-system"},"spec":{"ports":[{"port":443,"targetPort":8443}],"selector":{"k8s-app":"kubernetes-dashboard"}}}
  creationTimestamp: "2019-04-24T22:21:15Z"
  labels:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  name: kubernetes-dashboard
  namespace: kube-system
  resourceVersion: "1753"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kubernetes-dashboard
  uid: 4612785f-66df-11e9-8180-000c29e7b067
spec:
  clusterIP: 10.110.50.44
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
  - nodePort: 31394
    port: 443
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8443
  selector:
    k8s-app: kubernetes-dashboard
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
status:
{}
```

```
kubectl -n kube-system get service kubernetes-dashboard
```

```
nano admin-user.yaml

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
```

```
kubectl create -f admin-user.yaml
```

```
nano cluster-role.yaml

apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
metadata:
  name: admin-user
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cluster-admin
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: admin-user
  namespace: kube-system
```

```
kubectl create -f cluster-role.yaml
```

```
kubectl -n kube-system describe secret $(kubectl -n kube-system get secret | grep admin-user | awk '{print $1}')
```

https://youtu.be/nZ-CDc7PjSg

Answer (score 0):

This is how I make dashboard accessbile over network.

```
kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard port-forward svc/kubernetes-dashboard-kong-proxy 8443:443 --address 0.0.0.0
```

Answer (score -1):

looks like the token is Base64 encoded. Did you tried to decode it before pasting it into the token field? see: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/#decoding-a-secret

Comment: I tried by passing token value, it throws error 'Invalid Input'