# Is there a way to access kubernetes dashboard by passing token on the url?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-dashboard

I am able to access my kubernetes dashoard UI by accessing below url and providing the token and hitting sign in button on the login screen

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/#/workloads?namespace=default
```

Is there a way I can pass the token via the URL itself so the Dashboard UI opens in logged in state so i don't need to manually past the token and hit sign in?

I am looking for something like this (which was suggested by ChatGPT which unfortunately didn't work, this just opens the login screen again) :

```
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/kubernetes-dashboard/services/https:kubernetes-dashboard:/proxy/?token=<authentication-token>
```

Comment: Are you looking to access the UI by using the token in the URL or are you going to use the dashboard API with curl.

Comment: To access the UI on the browser

Comment: Maybe this answer helps? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46664104/how-to-sign-in-kubernetes-dashboard

Comment: No it doesn't. My question is about launching the dashboard in a logged in state. Which they haven't addressed

Comment: yeah, I am not sure that is possible... I've used Postman in the past with an `Authorization: Bearer <token>` header  and works, but it's not the ui in browser. Can you try to name your query param `?bearer-token=<auth-token>` instead? I am not sure if works thouth, just an idea.

Comment: no it didn't 

Answer (score 0):

We can access the kubernetes dashboard UI by two ways

1. [Bearer
   token](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#putting-a-bearer-token-in-a-request)
2. KubeConfig

As to answer your question, we can't login by encoding the token in the URL. **But we can use `Skip` option to avoid giving the token every time we login**.

To enable the `Skip` button to appear in UI we need to add following flags in the dashboard deployment under `args` section

```
--enable-skip-login
--disable-settings-authorizer
```

After adding these flags the deployment looks something like this

```
spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubernetes-dashboard
        image: k8s.gcr.io/kubernetes-dashboard-amd64:v1.10.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8443
          protocol: TCP
        args:
          - --enable-skip-login
          - --disable-settings-authorizer        
          - --auto-generate-certificates
          
          # If not specified, Dashboard will attempt to auto discover the API server and connect
          # to it. Uncomment only if the default does not work.
          # - --apiserver-host=http://my-address:port
        volumeMounts:
```

Now when you redeploy the dashboard you are able to see the `Skip` button. By skipping the login will save a lot of time when testing locally deployed clusters.

**Note: This is not a suggested method in terms of security standpoint. However, if you are deploying in an isolated testing environment you can proceed with the above steps.**

For more information refer this [link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/bypassing-authentication-for-the-local-kubernetes-cluster-dashboard/)

Comment: It seems this comment is out of date. The `Kubernetes-dashboard` project now ships with a number of deployments and it's not clear which of the deployments needs to be updated with these arguments.